# Script for dropdown menu Javascript PDF

Tags: acrobat

I am trying to write a script, javascript that goes in a PDF. It needs to bring up a drop down window with six choices, each choice is at least 4 lines, once chosen it needs to populate the field with that choice.

Nothing I have has worked, does anybody know javascript for this function. And where to put it in pdf, calculate, format???? ect.

No not generate a pdf. I have a form, I built in indesign using the interactive features, then exported to a pdf. There are two fields that are drop downs. In Adobe InDesign I can enter the 4 line paragraph choices but when you make the interactive PDF and choose one of the forms it only posts one line of the choice you made, there are three other lines. I just need a script I can paste into the javascript area of acrobat that would allow it to flow to all 4 lines after the choice is made. I could send an example if there is a place where I can pay to have the script written

Comment: please be more specific. What do you try to achieve? Have javascript generate a PDF?? *Good luck* - I don't think this would work. On the server side (Java, PHP, Python, Perl, ...) you can generate a PDF, but not on the client side.

Comment: its for a pdf not a website

Comment: please update your post to include your last comment.

Comment: No its just a pdf for our department to use to track errors. They just cant have the six paragraph choices on one page and need to be able to choose one of the paragraph choices and have it populate the field that's all. No website just a pdf.

Comment: As I said: Please add this information to your stackoverflow post (question), not only in the comments

Comment: Alexander I am new... how do you edit the question box?

Comment: There should be an "edit" link below the box